# How many downvotes does this answer have?

Tags: support, reputation

I posted [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/239433/70842), which I suspect is getting downvotes because I have a bunch of karma from it but it only has a score of 3.

A commenter leads me to believe people find the answer unsatisfactory because they are mixing up the result of Bell's Inequality with the concept of measurement resolution.  If this is true, I may as well set the record straight with a detailed edit.  If I'm not getting that many downvotes, I'll just make a quick reply comment.

Can someone with enough rep please tell me how many downvotes I have on that answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all voting activity so far happened within the same day (as here), it's easiest 
to go to your [reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), group the events by post, and expand the post of interest. The upvotes and downvotes are listed there.

Otherwise, one needs a userscript or a bookmarklet. There is a popular userscript [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/q/3082) for this purpose. I tend to use my own bookmarklet [vote split](http://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/#split) instead; this is how I see +8 -5 split without having 1000 rep here. (To use, drag the bold link from that page to your browser bar; then navigate to the post and click the bookmarklet.)